# RFID reader ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, interface

I got my hands on one RFID reader. It works as a simple keyboard input.
So if i open texeditor and scan some RFID it prints the code as text =)

I install RFDump and i have a problem finding serial port for it.
I got small script that prints me this

```
/dev/video1 - Chicony_Electronics_Co._Ltd._HD_WebCam
/dev/video0 - Chicony_Electronics_Co._Ltd._HD_WebCam
/dev/input/event7 - Chicony_Electronics_Co._Ltd._HD_WebCam
/dev/input/event17 - Sycreader_RFID_Technology_Co.__Ltd_SYC_ID_IC_USB_Reader_08FF20140315
/dev/input/event6 - Logitech_USB_Receiver
/dev/input/mouse1 - Logitech_USB_Receiver
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 08ff:0009 AuthenTec, Inc. SYC ID&IC USB Reader
```

-v option dosnt show any extra path o so

If copy that path (/dev/input/event17) in RFDump serial port it says:

```
Could not initialize RFID reader.
```

Hope this makes sense. If some can share some words of wisdom to make it work well be rly nice

---

@Sebastian
i run `dmesg| grep 'SYC ID&IC USB Reader'`
And output:

```
29571.975761] usb 1-2: Product: SYC ID&IC USB Reader
[29571.981465] input: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:08FF:0009.0004/input/input29
[29572.040908] hid-generic 0003:08FF:0009.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[32328.119438] usb 1-2: Product: SYC ID&IC USB Reader
[32328.124927] input: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:08FF:0009.0005/input/input30
[32328.183192] hid-generic 0003:08FF:0009.0005: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[35006.291923] usb 1-1: Product: SYC ID&IC USB Reader
[35006.298447] input: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:08FF:0009.0006/input/input31
[35006.357752] hid-generic 0003:08FF:0009.0006: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[35060.818770] usb 1-1: Product: SYC ID&IC USB Reader
[35060.824270] input: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:08FF:0009.0007/input/input32
[35060.884200] hid-generic 0003:08FF:0009.0007: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[35189.648009] usb 1-1: Product: SYC ID&IC USB Reader
[35189.653450] input: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:08FF:0009.0008/input/input33
[35189.713423] hid-generic 0003:08FF:0009.0008: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[37902.519864] usb 1-1: Product: SYC ID&IC USB Reader
[37902.525201] input: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:08FF:0009.0009/input/input34
[37902.584880] hid-generic 0003:08FF:0009.0009: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[42394.829746] usb 1-2: Product: SYC ID&IC USB Reader
[42394.835174] input: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:08FF:0009.000A/input/input35
[42394.898900] hid-generic 0003:08FF:0009.000A: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[42890.538133] usb 1-1: Product: SYC ID&IC USB Reader
[42890.543712] input: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:08FF:0009.000B/input/input36
[42890.607224] hid-generic 0003:08FF:0009.000B: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[43571.255468] usb 1-2: Product: SYC ID&IC USB Reader
[43571.260810] input: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:08FF:0009.000C/input/input37
[43571.320611] hid-generic 0003:08FF:0009.000C: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[45054.812926] usb 1-2: Product: SYC ID&IC USB Reader
[45054.818268] input: Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:08FF:0009.000D/input/input38
[45054.882301] hid-generic 0003:08FF:0009.000D: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Sycreader RFID Technology Co., Ltd SYC ID&IC USB Reader] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
```

@JayEye

```
Cannot open /dev/bus/usb/001/009
```

I found is /015 ( depens if i replug or so )

```
lsusb -v -D /dev/bus/usb/001/015
Device: ID 08ff:0009 AuthenTec, Inc. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x08ff AuthenTec, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0009 
  bcdDevice            0.08
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0022
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              4 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode           33 US
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      65
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
```

When I do it withut sudo says the original problem.
When with sudo i got popup:

```
Serial port not set. Please set the serial port in the preferences or use the -p argument and restart rfdump.
```

Also in preference, I have an opion in the Serial Port field: `/dev/ttyUSB0`

When exit sudo runned i got terminal info:

```
could not load preferences /root/.config/rfdump.ini : No such file or directory
using /usr/share/rfdump/rfdump.glade
```

So im confused in many ways =)

Comment: Try running `dmesg` in a terminal right after you plug it in. If it creates a virtual serial port, it should say which one there, something like ttyACM0 or similar.

Comment: What is the full output of lsusb -v for the device (in your case, `lsusb -v -D /dev/bus/usb/001/009`)

Comment: Also, how are you invoking rfdump?